# Not all cells autofill in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file, if I start typing letters inside cells some of them autofill but not all cells. I want all cells to autocomplete.

For example if I type 'H' in cell A1 it suggests me 'Hello' but if I type 'H' again inside cell A2 it doesn't suggest me anything. Why?

Comment: A1? Excel usually autocompletes based on the cell directly above the cell you're inputting in..

Comment: You might have more words that begin with H different than Hello